# Encountering Error while using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, wordnet

I am trying to extract the words(verbs) starting with R from [this page](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/r.html). But on executing the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url = "http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/r.html"
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
print soup.prettify()
```

The Error thrown was something like this:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u '\xa9' in position 57801: character maps to **undefined**

Can someone please tell me what the error is and how to fix and proceed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be much easier if you showed us *the whole* stack trace or, at least, at which line it points.

Anyway, I bet, the problem is with the last line. Change it to:

```
print(soup.prettify().encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm! Another question: Is there any way to write the error (Traceback) to a file so that it can be easily shared? (Else the only option is to type the entire thing!)

Comment: @RakshithNayak It's probably a good idea to get familiar with [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html). Really makes life easier once you spent an hour carefully exploring its abilities.